# Sparse Cholesky factorization algorithm for GPU

Tags: algorithm, math, cuda, opencl, gpgpu

Can anyone provide me with a parallel algorithm for calculating the sparse Cholesky factorization?  It must be suitable for execution on a GPU.  Any answers in CUDA, OpenCL, or even pseudo-code would be much appreciated.

Comment: Post some pseudo-code for doing this on a regular uniprocessor, and I'd be happy to discuss porting it to the GPU. Also, this is probably something that already exists... let me do a quick search. Aha. See my answer below.

Comment: Must it be a Cholessky factorization? In general sparse, iterative methods which can leverage a high performance spMV implementation are a far better fit to GPUs that direct solvers.

Comment: @talonmies - Ah! I shouldn't have been that specific.  What I really need is an algorithm that solves sparse symmetric system of linear equations.  The Cholesky factorization is what is currently being used to solve this problem.  However, in the case of the GPU, if other algorithms are more appropriate, I'm open to that.

Comment: @Jonathan, talonmies: Whether an iterative method will be faster than a direct factorisation is a non-trivial question. It depends significantly on how "hard" the matrix is (conditioning, structure, etc) and how sophisticated the iterative method is (the type of preconditioning etc). You would need to post significantly more details about the matrix for anyone to be able to guess about this kind of thing...

Comment: This might be appropriate for scicomp.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Generally speaking, direct sparse methods are not a great fit for the GPU. While the best direct solvers (thinking about packages like CHOLMOD, SuperLU, MUMPS here) use strategies to generate dense sub blocks which can be processed using L3 BLAS, the size and shape of the blocks don't tend to profit from using a GPU BLAS for acceleration. It doesn't mean it can't be done, just that the performance improvements may not be worth the effort.

Seeing as you are asking about a sparse Cholesky factorization, I assumed the matrix is symmetric positive definite. In that case you might consider using an iterative solver -- there are a number of good implementations of Conjugate Gradient and other Krylov subspace methods with simple preconditioners which might be of some use. The [Cusp](http://code.google.com/p/cusp-library/) library for CUDA might be worth investigating if your problem is amenable to iterative methods. The [ViennaCL](http://viennacl.sourceforge.net/) library offers something similar if you are looking for OpenCL.

Comment: I'm going to try the Conjugate Gradient method to begin with.  Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

The multi-frontal algorithm seems to be a popular choice for parallel sparse factorisation. Check out the `MUMPS` package, [here](http://graal.ens-lyon.fr/MUMPS/).

As I understand it, the code makes extensive use of level 3 `BLAS` calls (`DGEMM` and etc) to achieve high performance. I would investigate whether it's possible to link to a `GPU` based `BLAS` implementation, such as `CUDA BLAS` or the like if you're keen to use your `GPU` rather than `FPU`.

Contrary to dense factorisation, sparse methods always include a non-negligible amount of integer work in addition to the floating-point work done (though the floating-point is still dominant). I'm no expert on `GPU's`, but would the `CPU` be better suited for integer work than the `GPU`?? This might be an argument against implementing the whole algorithm for the `GPU`...

Hope this helps.

Comment: The integer thing, by itself, isn't an argument against GPUs. That being said, irregular memory access patterns/data structures (e.g. with pointers) and/or branching/divergent control flow are strong arguments against using the GPU. I'm no expert on sparse Cholesky factorizations, but doing sparse Cholesky is pretty much the poster child for irregular memory access and divergent control flow, right?

Comment: @Patrick87 - Good points. As I commented above, I should not have been so specific in my question. Any algorithm for solving a sparse symmetric system of linear equations will do.

Comment: @Pat: Good algorithms (i.e. multi-frontal, supernodal etc) use "blocked" updates, at least for the floating-point work, where quasi-dense sub-structure allow the use of dense kernels (i.e. `BLAS` routines). The initial "symbolic" integer phase generally involves irregular access, as far as I understand.

Answer (score 2):

Check out these articles, courtesy of the ACM (SC'08 and PPoPP '09 are excellent conferences).

V. Volkov, J. W. Demmel. Benchmarking GPUs to tune dense linear algebra. SC'08.

Jung, J.H., O’Leary, D.P. Cholesky Decomposition and
Linear Programming on a GPU. Scholarly Paper, University
of Maryland, 2006.

G. Quintana-Orti, F. D. Igual, E. S. Quintana-Orti, R. A. van de Geijn. Solving dense linear systems on platforms with multiple hardware accelerators. PPoPP '09.

If you don't have access to these through the ACM Portal/DL, they might be online somewhere. Otherwise... I can probably quote some of the most relevant sections, with citations, and have it be fair use.

EDIT:

Check this out maybe?

http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&cd=2&ved=0CB0QFjAB&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.netlib.org%2Flapack%2Flawnspdf%2Flawn223.pdf&rct=j&q=linpack%20gpu%20cholesky&ei=5nZOTtzCOYHAtgesmdSzBw&usg=AFQjCNGfQECpU6YJQhMRQYktlxpFKLFPjQ&cad=rja

EDIT2: Missed the part about "sparse".

Looking around online and at the ACM/IEEE, I don't see a lot that jumps out at me. What I do see doesn't sound promising... this might not be a computation where you see a lot of benefit from using the GPU.

Comment: These references all seem to be for dense matrix factorisation. Algorithms for sparse decomposition are a bit different...

Comment: Oh, totally missed that in the question. I'll take another look...

Answer (score 1):

Sparse Cholesky factorizations on a GPU is an open problem.  Even the [Linear Programming](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_programming) [paper](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.84.8623&rep=rep1&type=pdf) mentioned previously uses a dense algorithm while most problems are sparse.  The commercial LP solver market is very competitive, but nobody has a product that makes much use of the GPU yet.

Answer (score 0):

See [UHM](http://code.google.com/p/uhm/) - Unassembled Hyper Matrix solver. It can calculates sparse Cholesky factorization using multiple GPU on one host.